# Fragment.getView() always return null

Tags: android, android-fragments

I add two fragments to ViewPager in MainActivity dynamically,while I'm trying to get the sub view of the fragments, Fragment.getView() always return null, how can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

```
mLinearLayout= (LinearLayout)fragments.get(0).getView().findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);
    mRelativeLayout= (RelativeLayout) fragments.get(1).getView().findViewById(R.id.relative_layout);
```

Comment: getView() returns the Fragment View only after its onCreateView() has been completed. Otherwise it returns null.

Comment: so when should I get those sub views in MainActivity? I need to use them in MainActivity not in Fragment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I were you, I would use the fragments' `onCreateView()` to bind the views, then let the parent `Activity` know about the views through an Interface in `onActivityCreated()`.

Your interface could look like

```
public interface ViewInterface {
  void onLinearLayoutCreated(LinearLayout layout);
  void onRelativeLayoutCreated(RelativeLayout layout);
}
```

and then in each fragment

```
public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, inflater, false);
  mLinearLayout = layout.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);
  ...
  return layout;
}

...

public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
  try {
    ViewInterface callback = (ViewInterface) getActivity();
    callback.onLinearLayoutCreated(mLinearLayout);
  } catch (ClassCastException e) {
    Log.e("ERROR", getActivity().getName()+" must implement ViewInterface");
  }
  ...
}
```

and then in your parent `Activity` that implements `ViewInterface`

```
void onLinearLayoutCreated(LinearLayout layout) {
  //do something with LinearLayout
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a interface in the `Fragment`. Implement it in `Activity`. You will have the `Activity` instance in the `Fragment`. Now, inside `onActivityCreated()` of `Fragment`, call the interface method with `Activity` instance to notify that now the `getView()` returns its `View`.